# "De Morgan’s laws" vs "De Morgan's principles"

Tags: logic, terminology, fuzzy-logic

In the book *Fuzzy Logic with Engineering Applications* by Timothy J. Ross, it is written we can't write "De Morgan's laws"; instead, it should be "De Morgan's Principles". The authors used only "De Morgan's Principles" throughout the book.

I want to ask:

> Is there any difference between the two phrases, or are they the same?

Thank you!

Comment: A rapid Google search gives: "De Morgan's laws": 58500 answers vs. "De Morgan's principles": 296 answers only. And the winner is...

Comment: See page xvi: "The operations due to De Morgan are also not be referred to as a law, but as a *principle* . . . since this principle does apply to some (not all) uncertainty theories (e.g., probability and fuzzy)." That's all

Comment: @JeanMarie is this the criteria for truth I mean google search

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you I got the point

Comment: Not a criteria, but the weight of a survey that gives you a ratio 99.5% vs 0.5%... Personally, I had never heard about "de Morgan's principles". But I appreciate the reference of Mauro about fuzzy logic

Comment: @JeanMarie no problem Sir. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, from @MauroALLEGRANZA's reference I got the answer of my question....

Answer (score 0):

These are lines from the same book (3rd ed.) ref. by @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA. I hope these lines clear the point if someone else has the same confusion:

"The operations due to De Morgan are also not be referred to as a law, but
as a principle . . . since this principle does apply to some (not all) uncertainty theories (e.g., probability and fuzzy). The excluded middle axiom (and its dual, the axiom of contradiction) are not laws; Newton produced laws, Kepler produced laws, Darcy, Boyle,
Ohm, Kirchhoff, Bernoulli, and many others too numerous to list here all developed
laws. Laws are mathematical expressions describing the immutable realizations of nature.
Definitions, theorems, and axioms collectively can describe a certain axiomatic foundation
describing a particular kind of theory, and nothing more; in this case, the excluded middle and other axioms can be used to describe a probability theory. Hence, if a fuzzy set theory does not happen to be constrained by an excluded middle axiom, it is not a violation of some immutable law of nature like Newton’s laws; fuzzy set theory simply does not happen to have an axiom of the excluded middle – it does not need, nor is constrained
by, such an axiom." from (Fuzzy Logic with Engineering Applications by Timothy J. Ross)

Comment: So, presumably, I'll now have to start talking about the associative principle, and the principles of group theory and ... I think not! Ross is entitled to adopt any special terminology he likes, but I am unconvinced by this little rant against time-honoured standard usage.

Comment: @RobArthan, I agree with you. However, I think the question was asked only w.r.t. to that book not in general nomenclature. The answer is also according to that book.

Comment: Of course - I was just having my little rant!